# A property of submetry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $F:(\bar{M},g_{\bar{M}})\to (M,g_M)$ is a function, $F$ is called a submetry if for every $\bar{p}\in \bar{M}$ there is an $r>0$ such that $F(B(\bar{p},\varepsilon))=B(F(\bar{p}),\varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon\leq r$.

I find a property of submetry: suppose $r<\operatorname{inj}_p,\operatorname{inj}_{\bar{p}}$, if $d(p,q)<r$, then there exists a unique $\bar{q}\in F^{-1}(q)$ with $d(\bar{p},\bar{q})=d(p,q)$. I don't know how to prove it.